# boot problem with upgrading from ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: gnome

Bonjour

I have tried to upgrade from ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10, I've gotten an error:

> E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be
>   caused by held packages

I executed command

```
apt-get purge dpkg
```

after this system is not booting but giving following message in the biginning

```
init: hwclock main process (373) terminated with status 2
.:1: Can't open /etc/default/rcS
init:mountall main process(376) terminated with status 2
Filesystem check or mount failed
A maintenenace shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will termiante this shell and continue booting after re-typing 
filesystems. Any further errors will be ignored
root@ahmad-laptop:~#_
```

I hope you will have solution, please

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. I advise you to upgrade to 12.04.1 from live cd and backup all your data
2. you can recover your broken installation by going into grub rescue and fixing packages `sudo apt-get install -f`
3. ok try to unmount the disk umount /dev/sda* then do fsck again
4. boot from the livecd and try to fsck from there
5. install kile  `sudo apt-get install kile`
6. install Latex `sudo apt-get install texlive` then `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` then `sudo apt-get install gedit-latex-plugin`

Comment: The command sudo apt-get install -f returns following output: W:Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock    E:Unablee to write to /var/cache/apt/       E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened

Comment: here is the output, please>
W:Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock E:Unablee to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened

Comment: here is the result of umount
umount; /dev/sda: not mounted
umount; /dev/sda1: not mounted
umount; /dev/sda2: not mounted
umount; /dev/sda3: not mounted
umount; /dev/sda4: not mounted
umount; /dev/sd5: not mounted

Comment: output after command sudo fsck -f -p /dev/sda*
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 fsck.ext2:Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program? fsck:fsck.ntfs:not found fsck:Error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda1 fsck:fsck.ntfs:not found fsck:Error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda2 fsck:fsck.ntfs:not found fsck:Error 2 while executing fsck.swap for /dev/sda5 dosfsck 3.0.12,29 Oct 2011, FAT32, LFN

Comment: fsck.ext2:Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda4 Could this be zero-length partition? /dev/sda3: 637 files, 862134/1279168 clusters /dev/sda6: 809756/10829824 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 19267981/43304704 blocks

Comment: I still have the same output

Comment: any other solution or detail please

Comment: thank you very much kamil, upgrading is the best solution and I have all my data, thanks God

Comment: I had kile working on ubuntu 10.04 but I am not succeeding to find it on 12.04, may be because it is new to me??

Comment: what is the best way to install sty file of latex package, for example, (enumitem.sty)    ,,,,         Regards

Comment: Thank you for nice reply, I used command(sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras) but still colors of video are only like green and blue.

Comment: what color are you talking about? if your first question is solved please mark it as answer and ask another question. That may help people searching for answers to their problems

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem in your filesystem. To solve it:

from you grub menu go to recovery mode and then  drop to troot shell.

then issue this command:

```
sudo fsck -f -p /dev/sda*
```

Comment: Thank you , I executed this command and following is the output:

Comment: Where is the output?

Comment: fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2         
fsck.ext2:Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?
fsck:fsck.ntfs:not found
fsck:Error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda1
fsck:fsck.ntfs:not found
fsck:Error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda2
fsck:fsck.ntfs:not found
fsck:Error 2 while executing fsck.swap for /dev/sda5
dosfsck 3.0.12,29 Oct 2011, FAT32, LFN

Comment: fsck.ext2:Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda4
Could this be zero-length partition?
/dev/sda3: 637 files, 862134/1279168 clusters
/dev/sda6: 809756/10829824 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 19267981/43304704 blocks

Comment: ok try to unmount the disk `umount /dev/sda*`  then do fsck again

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but it returns the same output as I have wrtiien above.
I also have windows 7 in my computer. best regards

Comment: you are welcome but try to logout from windows and retry the same

Comment: thanks for your help. but I receive the same output as I mensioned above, regards, so the problem is still there and I am highly in tension

Comment: any solution please?

Comment: thanks, the problem is solved by one of the suggestions proposed above